# Else condition seemingly fails to execute

Tags: java, if-statement

I am creating a simple mathematics practice program, however I am running into a serious issue with my else conditions.  When the conditions that should trigger the else block to run, the if statement runs instead, ie if the program prompts the user to answer the question 7+6, if they input 5 it will still say procede as if they had input the proper answer.  I have combed through each iteration of this if else series (this is only one of 5) for the last few hours, but I cannot figure what is occurring to prevent the else segment from running.

correctrange / correctrange2 are random generated int values (currently they are always 7 & 6 respectively
d1 & d2 are the same values as doubles
human is an error parameter 
when input1 = q the program is supposed to end
EDIT: Here is an updated version, however the error persists

```
  //Addition    
    boolean addition = false;
while(input1 == 'A'|| input1 == 'a')
{
    System.out.println("What is the solution to the problem " + correctRange 
            + " + " +  correctRange2 );
    double input2 = userinput.nextDouble();
    if(input2 <= (d1 + d2) + human || 
       input2 >= (d1 + d2) - human)
    {System.out.println("That is correct!");
     System.out.println("What would you like to practice next?");
     addition = true;
    }
    while (!addition) 
    {System.out.println("The correct solution is " +
                correctRange + correctRange2);
        input1 = 'q';
        }
    input1 = userinput.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Where is an `else` block in your code? Also, `while (addition = false)`, with one equal sign, is *incorrect* (because that is assignment).

Comment: I now see that I at some point changed my else to a while condition, I only recently added the boolean system I have now.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `userinput.nextDouble()` it reads a new double. If you call it twice it expect a new double.

```
if(userinput.nextDouble() <= (d1 + d2) + human || 
   userinput.nextDouble() >= (d1 + d2) - human)
```

This read one or two double if the first condition is false.

Most likely you intended to do

```
double input = userinput.nextDouble();
if(input <= (d1 + d2) + human || 
   input >= (d1 + d2) - human)
```

or you can write

```
if(Math.abs(input - (d1 + d2)) <= human)
```

Note: `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison so

```
while (addition = false)
```

is always `false`  what you intended is likely to be

```
while (addition == false)
```

or better

```
while (!addition)
```

Comment: That helped to clean up, however the issue persists, when the user provides the correct answer, the program proceeds as intended, however if they input an incorrect answer, the program still responds as if it were correct.

Comment: @TSmik I suggest you step through your code in your debugger so you can see when your code doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your condition:

```
if (input2 <= (d1 + d2) + human || 
    input2 >= (d1 + d2) - human)
```

Let's take your sample values: d1 = 6, d2 = 7, human = 0.

- The user enters 5: `5 <= (6+7)+0`? Yes, sure
- The user enters 13: `13 <= (6+7)+0`? Yes, still true
- The user enters 20: `20 <= (6+7)+0`? No, but:
- The user enters 20: `20 >= (6+7)-0`? Yes!

I think your condition should be:

```
if (input2 <= (d1 + d2) + human && 
    input2 >= (d1 + d2) - human)
```